# How to add change display shortcut key in manjaro xfce?

Tags: shortcut, display, xfce, manjaro

Is there a way to add change display shortcut key in manjaro xfce?
By change display shortcut, I mean a shortcut key that allows to change display between current displays. For example in windows, it is `win+P` key.
Thank you in advanced

Comment: What research have you done ?

Comment: I have searched for ways to add keyboard shortcut for display in xfce but I didnot find anything. @RMPR